# Rearrange the equation to make $K$ the subject: $Q=(aK^-2+bL^-2)^-1/2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been presented with this equation,

$Q=(aK^{-2}+bL^{-2})^{-1/2}$

and have to rearrange it to make K the subject. Can someone show me how to do this step by step? My main problem is how to get rid of the exponential ^-1/2...

The solution is supposed to be $K=Q\times\sqrt{a}$

Comment: To get rid of the $-1/2$ raise both sides of the equation to the power of $-2$.

Comment: That's my problem, how do I raise both sides of the equation to the power of -2?

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 1):

$Q^{-2} = aK^{-2}+bL^{-2}$ (raise both sides to $-2$)

$Q^{-2}-bL^{-2} = aK^{-2}$

$\frac{Q^{-2}-bL^{-2}}{a} = K^{-2} = \frac{1}{K^2}$

$K^2 = \frac{a}{Q^{-2}-bL^{-2}} \Rightarrow K = \pm\sqrt{\frac{a}{Q^{-2}-bL^{-2}}}$

Comment: I still don't see how the solution can be K=Q*sqrt(a)

Comment: It isn't. Where did you get that answer from?

Comment: It has to be, it says so in my book and was confirmed by my lecturer...